# Отключение способов доставки если в корзине есть определенные товары

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.

Пробую дописать/переписать имеющийся код для отключения способов доставки, если в корзине есть определенные товары, которые могут быть из разных категорий. Нашла вот такой код, который отключает доставку, если есть товар из определенной категории. Буду рада любой помощи в решении этого вопроса :)

```
function hide_shipping_count_based( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Count line items
    $count =  count( $package['contents'] );

    // Set variable
    $found = false;

    // Set term (category)
    $term = 'pizza';

    // Check count
    if( $count >= 1 ) {

        // Loop through line items
        foreach( $package['contents'] as $line_item ) {
            // Get product id
            $product_id = $line_item['product_id'];

            // Check for category
            if ( has_term( $term, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // True
    if ( $found ) {
        // Loop trough rates
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // Targeting
            if ( in_array( $rate->method_id, array( 'shipping_method_0_local_pickup21', 'shipping_method_0_local_pickup20', 'shipping_method_0_local_pickup22' ) ) ) {
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_count_based', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: как вы идентифицируете товары у которых не должно быть методов доставки?

Comment: @DarthKYL по id товара. Ранее пробовала через указание класса доставки для таких товаров, но не получилось с этим разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете изменить условие по которому определяете находится ли необходимый товар в корзине. Допустим у вас есть массив в котором вы храните id товаров

```
$product_ids = [1,2,3,4]; // значение массива замените на свои
```

После того как вы определили свой массив вы можете проверить есть ли какой то из товаров в корзине

```
foreach ( $package['contents'] as $line_item ) {
    if ( in_array( $line_item['product_id'], $product_ids ) ) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```